# Mark workflow as non-check workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible within GitHub Actions to mark a workflow as something that is not a check? I can't find a hint inside the (good) documentation unfortunatly

I have included two default workflows to label pull requests and to greet first time contributors, but i don't want those workflows to be listed as "checks" since they aren't checking anything.

See here: https://github.com/wujood/awesome-gamejam/pull/3

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's not possible if you're triggering on the `pull_request` event. As a workaround you could try using a `schedule` or another event as a trigger.

As per https://github.blog/changelog/2019-09-24-ui-changes-in-github-actions-checks/ they explicitly changed the UI to don't display some checks.

> GitHub Actions uses the Checks API for representing and storing information about job executions.
> [...]
> At the same time, Actions can be triggered not just when somebody pushes code to GitHub but when many other events occur. In these cases, GitHub Actions looks for workflow files in the default branch of the repository and creates and associates the checks with the SHA of the latest commit.
> [...]
> We have found that this can be noisy and not relevant in the context of a pull request. It can also cause friction when protected branch rules are enabled. As of today, we’re deploying a change to **remove checks generated due to events other than** `push` and `pull_request` from the context of pull requests or in the calculation of commit statuses. These checks will be available in the Actions tab for observability.

(**emphasis** mine)

And also:

> GitHub Actions use the Checks API to output statuses, results, and logs for a workflow. GitHub creates a new check suite for each workflow run. The check suite contains a check run for each job in the workflow, and each job includes steps.

source: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/managing-workflow-runs/using-workflow-run-logs

There is also the following closed issue corresponding to the UI change described above: https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/86.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up! I just saw that it is possible to use the default github action labeler with pull_request_target as trigger, but this is also handled as a check. Other triggers are not really an option/solution.

Comment: `pull_request_target` was introduced after the blog post about the UI change, that's why it is not mentioned there. But it makes sense that it works analogously to `pull_request`.